# going trough the position of a specific character using mysql select statement

Tags: mysql

sorry for the title..

my problem is on how to get a specific part of a URL using mysql select statement for example the url

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=lpol&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs
```

and

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=query+to+count+specific+character&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs#hl=fil&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&sa=X&ei=J1knUPu9GsiUiAe3xYB4&ved=0CEQQvwUoAQ&q=mysql+query+to+go+through+specific+character+position&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=c4fd06cd155ee554&biw=1014&bih=424
```

these two are different url's but they both have google.com in their url so how can i get the google.com so i can count these 2 url in to 1 using mysql select statement

Comment: try using  function [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SUBSTRING_INDEX function should work

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('http://www.mysql.com/abcd/asd/', '/', 3); -> 'www.mysql.com'
```

Use this in combination with the column that you have.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', 3) FROM table; -> URLS without slashes
```

im no entierly sure about the 3 it could be 2.

Goodluck.